# What are the steps to create a custom drawing tool in inkscape's toolbox similar to “Create stares and polygons”?

Tags: inkscape

I want to add this custom tool with a custom **"Snap Controls Bar"**.
A tool that creates two lines and we can change lines's properties in **"Snap Control Bar"**

1. Length
2. Alignment
3. Left most points distance
4. Right most points distance

That will result into two lines that can be customize according to those parameters.
[image]

I am new to inkscape and I searched a lot about this but i am unable to find any useful resources for that.
It will be very helpfull if someone can tell me from where should i start looking into source code for that or any useful tutorial links.

Steps to create a custom tool may include something like

1. Add a new tool type in toolbox in some source code file.
2. Add properties for that tool into its **"Snap Controls Bar"**.
3. Add defination of properties in **"Snap Controls Bar"** for that tool.
4. Get values from properties and draw lines according to given properties.
5. ..etc

If any one thinks that this question need more clearity then please let me know. Post a comment.

Comment: This question reads like it could only be answered by an inkscape tutorial, which is an off-topic question on StackOverflow. On top of that you describe a programming goal, but do not ask about a specific programming problem, which is not focused enough a question. Please take the [tour], read [ask] and check [help/on-topic].

Comment: Thanks for your response. i keep only inkscape tag. How can i asked about a specific 
 programming problem if i don't know where to start and there are no resources for that because inkscape is building documentions. This question will help those whom want to understand source code. This is about "a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development"

Comment: This is a question about Inkscape development. Please read https://inkscape.org/develop/getting-started/

Comment: thanku for that. i asked this question becuase inkscape's team don't really provide such details about source code and if i start looking for myself then this may takes too much time to do this little thing becuase inkscape's source code is like a ocean and what i want to make is like finding a particular fish inside ocean. here i am asking for help something like where should i look into ocean to find that particular fish.

Comment: [here](https://inkscape.org/forums/beyond/what-are-the-steps-to-create-a-custom-drawing-tool-in-inkscapes-toolbox-similar-to-create-stares-and-polygons-for-a-b/) someone guided me.